# ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Tags: oracle

I am trying to run the query on an Oracle database

```
select 
  to_date(trunc(sysdate) || '13:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS') 
from dual;
```

and get the error

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL> alter session set nls_Date_format = 'DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> select trunc(sysdate, 'DD') + 13/24 from dual;

TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DD'
------------------
29-AUG-15 13:00:00
```

Comment: Shorter is `select trunc(sysdate)+13/24 from dual;` The `trunc` function 'cuts off' the time part.

Comment: note: the alter session is only necessary to demonstrate the result. It is not part of the solution.

Comment: I prefer `trunc(sysdate) + interval '13' hour` for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This is a runtime error. The date function has a problem to convert the date string. so display the date string to see what you want to convert:

```
select trunc(sysdate) || '13:00:00' from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

> to_date( trunc( sysdate ) || '13:00:00','DD-MON-YY HH24:MI:SS' )

An Innocent-looking query ...   but with nasty, implicit Type Conversions *all over* the place.

Breaking it down:

- Start with sysdate(). (**DATE** Data Type)
- Truncate that value, to remove the Time portion. (Still a **DATE** Data Type)
- *Implicitly cast* that value into a **VARCHAR**, using whatever NLS_DATE_FORMAT happens to be in force, then concatenate the time bit on the end of that, *without* any intervening space to separate the two bits, and finally
- Try to convert the resulting varchar value *back* into a **DATE** Data Type, using the *explicit* format given (which, by the way, *includes* a space between the data and Time portions).

If those internal conversions don't give you something that *exactly matches* that Date/Time parsing pattern?  Boom!

Remove the last to_date() call and see what [varchar] value you're actually getting.

I suspect this will work if you *remove* the explicit Date/Time "pattern" and use whatever [NLS setting] the database is currently using.